# iOS 5.1 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: called but didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: is not on first load

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5.1

So it looks like the first time I push a UIVIewController to my UINavigationController stack this method is called:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

But this method is not:

```
-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Now if I rotate the device after the UIViewContoller is loaded then both of these are fired as expected.

Why is `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` not being called when my controller loads?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: just updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation%3a):

> didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
>
> Sent to the view controller after the user interface rotates.

`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` is not being called during load because there was no user interface rotation.

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is called before every rotation. I am not sure why it's called during load. I think it could be a matter of some performance optimalization hint used by `UINavigationViewController`.